# How to create a file screen exception in powershell (FSRM Api)

Tags: file, powershell, scripting, server

I need to create file screen exception in powershell using the FSRM Api, I am using this script to create the cuota but I am having trouble to commit the object.

Because I haven't achieved to meet the requirement to modify ***AllowedFileGroups*** property :(

```
$FSRMObject = New-Object -Com Fsrm.FsrmFilescreenManager
$createFileScreenException = $FSRMObject.CreateFileScreenException("c:\")
$createFileScreenException.AllowedFileGroups("Text Files")
$createFileScreenException.Commit()
```

This is what I get Listing the Properties and Methods of the Object, in the property definition of ***AllowedFileGroups*** I can see that I need to create IFsrmMutableCollection.

Does anyone have an idea of how to create the file screen exception?

[image: Listing the Properties and Methods of a Command or Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can create the simplest quota using the FSRM api in powershell, to view more modificable options get the members of the object $quota.

```
$fsrmQuotaObject = New-Object -Com FSrm.FsrmQuotaManager
$quota = $fsrmQuotaObject.CreateQuota("c:\path")
$quota.ApplyTemplate("Select template")
$quota.Commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

`AllowedFileGroups` is a property, not a method, so I'd expect something like this to work:

```
$createFileScreenException = $FSRMObject.CreateFileScreenException('c:\')
$createFileScreenException.AllowedFileGroups = 'Text Files'
$createFileScreenException.Commit()
```

Can't test it, though.

Comment: I have tested it but it doesnt work. this is the exception that I get while runing that @ansgar

Comment: System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: Exception setting "AllowedFileGroups": "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))" ---> System.Management.Automation
                        .SetValueInvocationException: Exception setting "AllowedFileGroups": "Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))" ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (
                        0x80020005): Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))

Comment: Try `@('Text Files')` instead of `'Text Files'`.

Comment: System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "CreateFileScreenException" with "1" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045304" ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvoc
                        ationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80045304): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045304

Comment: Hi this is the new exception that I am getting running with $createFileScreenException.AllowedFileGroups.Add(@('Text Files'))

Comment: Who said anything about `.AllowedFileGroups.Add()`?

Comment: I get the first exception in the comments ,that says type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))" -

Comment: I have also tried removing the .add in the AllowedFileGroups and i get this exeption

Comment: Exception             : System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "CreateFileScreenException" with "1" argument(s): "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045304" ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvoc
                        ationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80045304): Exception from HRESULT: 0x80045304

Comment: Like I said: I don't have an environment where I could test, so this is as far as I can help.

Comment: thaks for all the help, I am still investigating how to do it. if you need an environment and want continue investigating y could give you a remote connection to a server with the FSRM role installed.